# Django - Convert value get from HTML select in POST request back to number before validate ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

In my model, I have a field which is populated from 'choices' like following:

```
PRIORITY = (
    (0, 'Low'),
    (1, 'Medium'),
    (2, 'High'),
)

priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY, default=0)
```

So in my DB, it will be stored as 0, 1 or 2.

This **priority** field will be displayed by HTML **select** tag. I am using **instance.get__priority__display** to get the display of the **priority** field.

Now I have a model form that will take this **priority**:

```
class NewItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['priority']
```

In my view, when user click a button, my function in **views.py** will take the value selected by user and store it in a new item in database. But my problem now is that because the value I got from POST request is **Low, Medium** or **High**,  not **0, 1 or 2** so when I use **is_valid()**, it said my form is not valid and I can not create the new item and store it in database.

Is there any way I can convert those POST data from HTML select tag back to number as in my **choices** and validate my ModelForm after that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your template code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should not be attempting to create the select element manually, whether with `get_priority_display` or not. You have a Django form; one of its two responsibilities[*] is to display the field. So:

```
{{ form.priority }}
```

will give you the select, with its internal and display values correctly set. And in the view

```
form.cleaned_data['priority']
```

will get you the correct value for that field.

[*] along with validation

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to change my template code when I start using ModelForm :)